# checkdnsrr false negative

Tags: php, dns

when using the checkdnsrr() function it sometimes says no record exists when it clearly does.

For example

```
$domain = 'ns1.huubknops.com.';
var_dump(checkdnsrr($domain, 'ANY'));
```

returns bool(false), indicating that no DNS record was found. However if i do:

```
print_r(dns_get_record($domain));
```

on the same domain it will return an A and AAAA record:

```
Array
(
[0] => Array
    (
        [host] => ns1.huubknops.com
        [type] => AAAA
        [ipv6] => 2001:888:1cf8::1
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 42450
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [host] => ns1.huubknops.com
        [type] => A
        [ip] => 83.160.95.99
        [class] => IN
        [ttl] => 42450
    )

)
```

This does not happen for all domains, only some. Is there any reason or fix for this?

Comment: Looks like, unless you specify the second arg, it searches for MX records by default.  Try `checkdnsrr('ns1.huubknops.com.', 'A')` or `checkdnsrr('ns1.huubknops.com.', 'ANY')`

Comment: Yep that was it. Feel stupid now!

Answer (score 1):

Do they implement round robin? The first comment at https://www.php.net/checkdnsrr indicates this could be a problem. The second result for IPv6 could cause similar problems